# Trying to create my first class, getting "object has no attribute file error"

Tags: python

I'm trying to teach myself object programming in python.
I want my verbals to be just for that instance of the object, which I thought was done by using self.verbalname.

Right now I getting an error for every line that has self.file in it saying 
OBJECT HAS NO ATTRIBUTE FILE
example in

```
def open(self):
    # open file
    self.file  = open(self.filename,"r",1);
```

I get the error message

CODE

```
class spreedsheet(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.filename = name

    def getFileName(self):
            print(self.filename)

    def open(self):
        # open file
THIS LINE GIVES ME A ERROR SAYING OBJECT HAS NO ATTRIBUTE FILE
        self.file  = open(self.filename,"r",1);

    def close(self):
        # close file
THIS LINE GIVES ME A ERROR SAYING OBJECT HAS NO ATTRIBUTE FILE
        self.file.close();

    def addString(self,add):
        # add a string to a line of the spreed sheet
THIS LINE GIVES ME A ERROR SAYING FILE DOES NOT EXIST
        self.file.write(add)
        self.write(",")

    def addStringRet(self,name):
        # add a string to a line of the spreed sheet
THIS LINE GIVES ME A ERROR SAYING FILE DOES NOT EXIST
        self.file.write(add)
        self.write("\r\n")
       # Add a new string and start a new col



myobject = spreedsheet("agraphdata.txt")
myobject.addString("tedt")
myobject.close()
```

Comment: You just forgot to call `myobject.open()`. Closing for (sort-of) typo.

Comment: define self.file inside __init__ function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined an instance variable `file` on the `spreadsheet` class anywhere, so the instance methods do know know what it is. Add it to your constructor:

```
class spreedsheet(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.filename = name
        self.file = None

    def getFileName(self):
        print(self.filename)

    def open(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename,"r",1);

    etc
```

Comment: But without calling `open`, this will not fix the problem.

Comment: You are correct, but that is not his question. He asked about missing `file`. He will see the error you mention later.

Comment: Also, one shouldn't handle file handles the way he does. Much better to `with open(self.file_name, 'r') as in_file: return in_file.readlines()` or something, so the `in_file` is closed when you step out of the statement.